# PHP undefined index id error

Tags: php, forms, post

I am trying to submit this form and upon the submission it should redirect to itself back. However, the problem I am facing is that, after I submit the form it display this error:

```
Notice: Undefined index: id in C:\xampp\htdocs\iNetLink\configuration.php on line 9
```

Here is my form file:

```
    <?php include("header.php");

if(ISSET($_POST['node'])){
  $nodeID = $_POST['node'];
}else{
  $nodeID = 0;
}

$requestID = $_GET['id'];
$qConfigurationForm = "SELECT * FROM configuration WHERE request_id = '$requestID' ";
$rConfigurationForm = $connection->query($qConfigurationForm);

$rowCount = $rConfigurationForm->rowCount();
$row = $rConfigurationForm->fetch();

if($rowCount > 0){
?>
<section id="content">
  <section class="vbox">
    <section class="scrollable padder">

      <ul class="breadcrumb no-border no-radius b-b b-light pull-in">
        <li><a href="index.html"></a></li>
      </ul>
      <div class="m-b-md">
        <h3 class="m-b-none">Configuration</h3>
      </div>
      <section class="panel panel-default">
      <!-- Tabs for navigation -->
        <?php include("tabs.php");?>
      </section>
      <!-- Tabs for navigation ended -->

      <!--forms-->
      <section class="panel panel-default">
          <header class="panel-heading font-bold">Line Configuration Information</header>
          <div class="panel-body">
          <form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="configuration.php" data-validate="parsley">
          <div class="col-md-6">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-sm-3 control-label" for="requestID"></label>
              <div class="col-sm-6">
                  <input type="hidden" name="requestID" id="requestID" value="<?php echo $requestID;?>">
                  <input type="hidden" name="isUpdate" value="1" />
              </div>
          </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Node</label>
                  <div class="col-sm-6">
                  <select name="node" id="node" class="form-control m-b" onchange="GetId()" data-required="true">
                  <option></option>
                  <?php

                    $qNode = "SELECT id,node FROM node WHERE id = '$nodeID'";
                    $rNode = $connection->query($qNode);

                    foreach($rNode as $node){
                    $nodeid = $node['id'];
                    $nodeName = $node['node'];

                    echo "<option value=\"$nodeid\" selected=\"selected\">$nodeName</option>";
                    }
                    echo "<optgroup></optgroup>";

                    $qNode = "SELECT id,node FROM node WHERE `status` = 1";
                    $rNode = $connection->query($qNode);

                    foreach($rNode as $node){
                    $nodeid = $node['id'];
                    $nodeName = $node['node'];

                    echo "<option value=\"$nodeid\">$nodeName</option>";
                    }
                  ?>
                  </select>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Connection Type</label>
                  <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <select name="connectionType" id="connectionType" class="form-control m-b" data-required="true">
                      <option></option>
                      <?php

                          $connection_type = $row['connection_type'];

                          $qConnectionConfigType = "SELECT * FROM `connection_type_config` WHERE id = '$connection_type'";
                          $rConnectionConfigType = $connection->query($qConnectionConfigType);

                          foreach($rConnectionConfigType as $connectionConfigType){
                            $connectionConfigID = $connectionConfigType['id'];
                            $connectionType = $connectionConfigType['connection_type'];

                            echo "<option value=\"$connectionConfigID\" selected=\"selected\">$connectionType</option>";
                            }
                            echo "<optgroup></optgroup>";

                            $qConnectionConfigType = "SELECT * FROM `connection_type_config`";
                            $rConnectionConfigType = $connection->query($qConnectionConfigType);

                            foreach($rConnectionConfigType as $connectionConfigType){
                              $connectionConfigID = $connectionConfigType['id'];
                              $connectionType = $connectionConfigType['connection_type'];

                              echo "<option value=\"$connectionConfigID\">$connectionType</option>";
                            }
                         ?>
                    </select>
                  </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-sm-3 control-label" for="timeSlot">Time Slot</label>
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="timeSlot" name="timeSlot" value="<?php echo $row['time_slot'];?>" data-required="true">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-sm-3 control-label" for="dslUnifiNo">DSL/Unifi Username</label>
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="dslUnifiNo" name="dslUnifiNo" value="<?php echo $row['dsl_username'];?>">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-sm-3 control-label" for="remarksConfig">Remarks</label>
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                <textarea rows="4" cols="50" class="form-control" id="remarksConfig" name="remarksConfig"><?php echo $row['remarks'];?></textarea>
                </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-md-6">

          <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Port</label>
                  <div class="col-sm-6">
                  <select name="portNo" id="portNo" name="portNo" class="form-control m-b" data-required="true">
                  <!-- <option></option>
                  <?php

                    $qPortNo = "SELECT * FROM node_port WHERE node_id = '$nodeID' AND `status` = 1";
                    $rPortNo = $connection->query($qPortNo);

                    foreach($rPortNo as $portNo){
                    $portID = $portNo['id'];
                    $number = $portNo['port_no'];

                    echo "<option value=\"$portID\">$number</option>";
                    }
                  ?> -->
                  </select>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">E1 Circuit No.</label>
                  <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <select name="e1circuitNo" id="e1circuitNo" class="form-control m-b">
                      <option></option>
                      <?php
                            $e1_circuit_no = $row['e1_curcuit_no'];

                            $qE1Type = "SELECT * FROM `e1_type` WHERE id = '$e1_circuit_no'";
                            $rE1Type = $connection->query($qE1Type);

                            foreach($rE1Type as $e1Type){
                              $e1ID = $e1Type['id'];
                              $type = $e1Type['type'];

                              echo "<option value=\"$e1ID\" selected=\"selected\">$type</option>";
                            }
                            echo "<optgroup></optgroup>";

                            $qE1Type = "SELECT * FROM `e1_type`";
                            $rE1Type = $connection->query($qE1Type);

                            foreach($rE1Type as $e1Type){
                              $e1ID = $e1Type['id'];
                              $type = $e1Type['type'];

                              echo "<option value=\"$e1ID\">$type</option>";
                            }
                         ?>
                    </select>
                  </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Changed Date</label>
              <div class="col-sm-6">
                <input class="input-m input-m form-control" type="date" 
                data-date-format="dd-mm-yyyy" id="changedDate" name="changedDate" value="<?php echo $row['changed_date'];?>" data-required="true">
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-sm-3 control-label" for="dslUnifiIp">DSL/Unifi IP</label>
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="dslUnifiIp" name="dslUnifiIp" value="<?php echo $row['dsl_ip'];?>">
                </div>
            </div>
            <br/>
            <br/>
            <br/>
            <br/>
            <br/>
            <br/>
            <br/>
            <br/>
            <br/>
            <br/>
            <br/>
            <br/>
              <div class="btn-toolbar pull-right">
              <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?=$requestID;?>">
              <input class="btn btn-warning " type="reset" value="Reset" name="reset" >
              <input class="btn btn-info " type="submit" value="Save Draft" name="saveDraft">
              <input class="btn btn-success " type="submit" value="Submit" name="Submit">
              </div>
          </div>
          </form>
          </div>
      </section>
```

Line 9 is the `$requestID = $_GET['id'];`

Here is the executer for the form:

```
    <?php
include("dbconnection.php");
session_start();
/* 
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
$requesterID = $_SESSION['id'];
print_r($_POST);
$node = $_POST['node'];
$connectionType = $_POST['connectionType'];
$timeSlot = $_POST['timeSlot'];
$dslUnifiNo = $_POST['dslUnifiNo'];
$remarksConfig = $_POST['remarksConfig'];
$port = $_POST['port'];
$e1circuitNo = $_POST['e1circuitNo'];
$changedDate = $_POST['changedDate'];
$dslUnifiIp = $_POST['dslUnifiIp'];
$requestID = $_POST['requestID'];


if(ISSET($_POST['isUpdate'])){
    $qinsert = "UPDATE configuration SET
            node = '$node',
            connection_type = '$connectionType',
            time_slot = '$timeSlot',
            dsl_username = '$dslUnifiNo',
            remarks = '$remarksConfig',
            port = '$port',
            e1_curcuit_no = '$e1circuitNo',
            changed_date = '$changedDate',
            dsl_ip = '$dslUnifiIp'
            WHERE request_id = '$requestID'";
}else
{
    $qinsert = "REPLACE INTO configuration SET
            node = '$node',
            connection_type = '$connectionType',
            time_slot = '$timeSlot',
            dsl_username = '$dslUnifiNo',
            remarks = '$remarksConfig',
            port = '$port',
            e1_curcuit_no = '$e1circuitNo',
            changed_date = '$changedDate',
            dsl_ip = '$dslUnifiIp',
            request_id = '$requestID'";

            $requestID = $connection->lastInsertId();
            if($status == 1){
                $action = "lineApplication.php";
                $dateCreated = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
                $userTypeID = 5;

                $qinsertTss = "INSERT INTO notifications SET
                                user_id = '$requesterID',
                                action = '$action',
                                item_id = '$requestID',
                                created_at = '$dateCreated',
                                receive_user_type_id = '$userTypeID'";

                $rinsertTss = $connection->query($qinsertTss);
            }
}
$rinsert = $connection->query($qinsert);

header("location:configuration.php?id=$requestID");
```

Help! :)

Comment: print `$_GET` and see waht's appearing. If `id` is not there then maybe its not passed. before redirecting log `configuration.php?id=$requestID` into a file using `file_put_contents` so it does not hinder the redirect.

Comment: you don't need to paste all code, just past relative code. i lost in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are sending you're POST to configuration.php not to your executer?

```
<form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="configuration.php" data-validate="parsley">
```

Also...

```
$requestID = $_GET['id'];
```

this will error because $_GET['id'] is not available during POST. to fix your code try this:

```
$requestID = (isset($_GET['id'])) ? $_GET['id'] : 'add ID for POST';
```

or make sure your form is sending in the right PHP file

Comment: i tried this solution, but it seems that now when it redirects, the ID is not pass with, the URL becomes configuration.php only there is no configuration.php?id=30

Comment: @Fadil check my edit

Comment: mark as accepted if this solve your problem